# ExpressJS sendFile() cannot send URL GET parameters

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm new to Node.js and Express.js and its routing. It's all set up correctly and it all works except for the following code.

I tried the following code:

```
app.get("/game/*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/game.html?gameId=" + /\/([^\/]+$)/.exec(req.url)[1]);
});
```

The goal was to send all requests with `/game/{gameId}` (where `gameId` is some number) to `/public/game.html?gameId={gameId}`.

It correctly gets the requests with `/game/`, gets the `gameId` parameter from the URL, and attempts to `sendFile()` it. However, the `sendFile()` does not work, saying:

> web.1  | Error: ENOENT, stat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/papei/public/game/32'

I've searched this error, and I guess it has to do with a file not being found. The problem is, `/public/game.html` exists. If I remove the `?gameId...` part in the `sendFile()`, then it works. But I guess the `sendFile()` is looking for an *exact* URL, and is not finding it.

Is there any way to send URL GET parameters using ExpressJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `sendFile` tries to find an exact match (which your query parameters break) as you thought.

You could use `express-static` to serve the html page, and then redirect to it as needed like so:

```
app.get("/game/:gameid", function(req, res) {
  // Not ideal, as it uses two requests
  res.redirect('/game.html?gameId=' + req.params.gameid)
});
```

Or you could put the html inside a template and render it for the response e.g:

```
app.get("/game/:gameid", function(req, res) {
  // Render the 'game' template and pass in the gameid to the template
  res.render('game', {gameid: req.params.gameid})
});
```

Either way, you don't need to use a catch all route and regex to get query parameters, see [req.params](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) or [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) in the express documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying the redirect right now, but it doesn't work. And I'm not sure how you would make a template -- could you provide documentation for that? Thanks.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `express-static`? Does it differ from the code I am currently using?

Comment: If you are trying to use the redirect, make sure your express-static middleware is below the route for the redirect. [Here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) is the documentation explaining template engines  and [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) is the documentation for serving static files (aka `express-static`).

Comment: I have no idea. This is part of the problem when you only show a small section of your code. Please include all relevant code, otherwise people can only speculate. I would suggest you look at using the template method - if you already have lots of html written you'll probably want to use something very similar (I'd suggest you look at handlebars).

Comment: It worked now. Thanks! And thanks for the extra info about the templates and req.params.

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! I'd highly suggest you work your way through the documentation (at-least the 'guides' section) to get a better basic understanding of express. You could also look at the default  [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) site as an example.